# Cannot derive from class with virtual inheritance (C++ virtual inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, virtual-inheritance

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(std::string arg1, std::string arg2) : arg1(arg1), arg2(arg2) {}
    string arg1,arg2;
    virtual void f() = 0;
    inline virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Mixin1 : virtual public Base
{
};

//Virtual class uses virtual base and a mixin
class VirtualDerived : virtual public Base, public Mixin1
{
public:
    VirtualDerived(string arg2) : Base("some literal", arg2) {}
};

//Here I am concretely subclassing VirtualDerived, whose constructor constructs all virtual superclasses.
class ConcreteDerived : public VirtualDerived
{
public:
    ConcreteDerived(string arg2) : VirtualDerived(arg2) {}
    inline void f() {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ConcreteDerived cd("hello");

    return 0;
}
```

I am deriving from VirtualDerived, whose constructor will initialize Base. Whether I explicitly declare VirtualDerived's inheritance of Mixin1 virtual or not makes no difference.

The error I get is that ConcreteDerived must explicitly call Base's constructor.

Making ConcreteDerived's inheritance virtual similarly makes no difference.

The problem is not with VirutalDerived's constructor forwarding. If I implement f to make it a concerete class, I can create it without issue:

```
class VirtualDerived : virtual public Base, public Mixin1
{
public:
    VirtualDerived(string arg2) : Base("some literal", arg2) {}
    inline void f(){}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    VirtualDerived cd("hello");

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler seems to understand that VirtualDerived's constructor calls Base's non-trivial constructor when VirtualDerived is created directly. But not if something derives VirtualDerived and calls it. Why is this the case?

Comment: "`virtual public Base, public Mixin1`" Why do you inherit from `Base` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand about virtual inheritance is that when you virtually inherit from a class, it goes to the "front" of the inheritance "queue"; that is, you must initialise virtual bases before all other base classes.

In this case, `ConcreteDerived` has `Base` as an indirect virtual base, via `VirtualDerived`. Since `Base` has no default constructor, you must specify it in the initialiser list of `ConcreteDerived`.

The reasoning is this: imagine you had another intermediate class such as

```
class VirtualDerived2 : virtual public Base
{
public:
    VirtualDerived2() : Base("arg1", "arg2") {}    
};
```

Here `VirtualDerived2` also virtually inherits from `Base`, and initialises it with its own set of arguments. Now we add another concrete class:

```
class ConcreteDerived2 : public VirtualDerived, public VirtualDerived2
{
    // ...
};
```

Now `ConcreteDerived2` has two base classes, both of which virtually inherit from `Base`. But you only have one copy of `Base` in the hierarchy -- that's the entire point of virtual inheritance. So now which parameters are you going to use to initialise your (single) copy of `Base`? Those from `VirtualDerived`, or those from `VirtualDerived2`? There is no good answer for this, so C++ makes you choose in the most derived class.

Comment: "_There is no good answer for this_" There is one good answer: the same answer C++ has for virtual functions. It's ambiguous in that particular case. That doesn't justify the rule that the most derived class should initialize virtual base classes.